# Opened_files very large

Tags: mysql

What is the reason my `Opened_files` is so large if i have `table_open_cache=200000 and max_connections = 20000`?

```
    mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'open%';
    +--------------------------+---------+
    | Variable_name            | Value   |
    +--------------------------+---------+
    | Open_files               | 618     |
    | Open_streams             | 0       |
    | Open_table_definitions   | 668     |
    | Open_tables              | 1003    |
    | Opened_files             | 2721799 |
    | Opened_table_definitions | 0       |
    | Opened_tables            | 0       |
    +--------------------------+---------+

cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
1048576

limit.conf
mysql soft nofile 40960
mysql hard nofile 90240

mysqld soft nofile 40960
mysqld hard nofile 90240
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, `Opened_files` is something like the counter of created file descriptors since the last status flush.

Here, your current number of opened files is 618. You can confirm this using `lsof`.